# Ajax loading screen with Prototype and unobtrusive JS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, prototype, loading, unobtrusive-javascript

I am looking for a solution of adding a loading screen (or frame) while ajax is loading the data. All the other posts I can find online is about jQuery rather than Prototype... I would swear that I will use jQuery for my next project. But anyway the code is like this, using unobtrusive JS:

in search.js.erb:

```
$("main_content").update("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "items")) %>");
```

for sure there is a search.html.erb with pretty similar content:

```
<%= render :partial => "items" %>
```

to add a loading screen, do I need to add something before this update function, or in the link_to statement, or somewhere else? I am totally new to this so please don't mind stupid questions. Thanks very much.

Update: I found something useful in the old **link_to_remote** function, which has a **:loading** and a **:loaded** tag to make the loading image or screen show up. However this has been totally not mentioned in the latest **link_to** of Rails 3. Is there any way to write it into the js file?